# cast literal to byte in F#

Tags: f#, casting

Here is my code snip:

```
let targetMeasure (usesPercent:Nullable<byte>) value =
            match usesPercent.Value with
            | 0 -> sprintf "$%A" value
            | _ -> sprintf "%A%%" value
```

Trying to match "usesPercent" with 0, but 0 needs to be a byte. This has always confused me in F#. I get past the nullable stuff, but then the values aren't of the same type. How do I get around this?

Comment: See also the docs for "Literals", which shows all the `0uy`-type stuff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233193.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let targetMeasure (usesPercent:Nullable<byte>) value =
    match usesPercent.Value with
    | 0uy -> sprintf "$%A" value
    | _ -> sprintf "%A%%" value
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create byte literal by writing `0uy`. A (pretty) complete list of numeric literals is printed by F# Interactive if you write some that is invalid (e.g. `0z`). Then you get:

> Sample formats include 4, 0x4, 0b0100, 4L, 4UL, 4u, 4s, 4us, 4y, 4uy, 4.0, 4.0f, 4I.

For integers, it is quite easy to decode `u` stands for unsigned and `y`, `s`, (nothing), `L` stand for 8bit, 16bit, 32bit and 64bit respectively.